# Not able to import ZXingObjC files even after correct pod install and project is building correctly too

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, zxing, cocoapods

I am trying to integrate `ZXingObjC` along with `CocoaPods`.

I have installed `CocoaPods` successfully. After that I have created one pod file using `pod init` command. Contents of Podfile are :

```
target "TestScanner" do

end

target "TestScannerTests" do
    pod 'ZXingObjC', '3.0'
end
```

After `pod install` workspace is created and I am opening that workspace instead of xcodeproj as suggested.

But in the end in my scanner project I am not able to import any of the .h file from `ZXingObjC` library.

I have no clue whats going wrong here.

Could you please help

Comment: How are you trying to import the `ZXingObjC` headers? and can you post some error logs?

Comment: I can see libsPod<SchemeName>.a file added into my frameworks. But its showing red. When i searched it says its a cocoapod error. So i went on ahead and tried importing in my code like our simple import statement #import <ZxingObjC/ZXingObjC.h>

Comment: One of the most annoying problem i am facing here is, it does not show me any error or warning for that matter. It just does not show any .h file from ZXingObjC as if its not getting added into my project.

Comment: Okay ultimately i figured out that my scheme name which i was mentioning in my pod file was incorrect. Also the latest version is 3.0.3 and not 3.0. Huh that was some silly mistake. Nevertheless, Can someone tell me how can I stop barcode getting scanned multiple times?

Comment: Well, to help a little bit with your CocoaPods import problem you could use it like this: `pod 'ZXingObjC', '~> 3.0'`. This way it will ensure the update to the latest version available without updating to version 4.0 (that will probably have some API changes or something like that).

Comment: The barcode problem should be discussed in another question probably

Comment: Hi Melnik, I tried integrating dependencies through 3.0 but they have few bugs in it e.g ZXParserResults.h is no more imported, also they have removed description property from ZXCalendarResult. These changes are available at 3.0.3. So i had to download it using pod 'ZXingObjC', '3.0.3'